# Blender Presenter View?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, interface

In Powerpoint, there is such a thing as a Presenter View where you have Powerpoint opened up on one monitor, say your laptop monitor and then you have the slides being viewed on another one. You use this view when you are presenting to an audience and it gives you a lot of control.

I am wondering if Blender has anything like that. So for example, in monitor 1, I can play with a cube (or a 3D molecule), moving it around and such and then in Monitor 2, I have the same cube moving around only here the audience can only see the cube. They cannot see any of the Blender interface or anything else.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blender is not a presenter kind of software.

You can detach any view as an additional window by pressing shift and dragging.

The new window you can move over to a second monitor or projector.

That window can be set to whatever part of the interface you want, and can be maximized to full screen by pressing Ctrl+Shift+SpaceBar

Comment: Thanks a lot! I figured as much but wondered if anything knew anything different. Cheers!